# Extract name of Google Sheet with googlesheets package

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I'm using the `googlesheets` package to get data from a Google Sheet and want to append the sheet name as a column in the data.frame.

For instance, with the public Gapminder sheet:

```
library(googlesheets)
library(dplyr)
my_dat <- gs_gap() %>% # register public Gapminder practice sheet
  gs_read(ws = 1) %>%
  mutate(source_dat = "Africa")
```

My last line does this manually, but I want to do it automatically, i.e., populate a variable `source_dat` with the name of the sheet. (*Yes, I know there's already a column with that info - this is just an example*).  Is there a way to reference the active sheet name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now only cell feed reading functions attach the worksheet name as an attribute. The second solution shows how you could use that. If you open an issue on github, I could add that to all read methods.

You could also store the name of the ws in advance, as in the first solution.

```r
library(googlesheets)
library(dplyr)

ws <- "Africa"
my_dat <- gs_gap() %>% # register public Gapminder practice sheet
  gs_read(ws = ws) %>%
  mutate(source_dat = ws)
#> Accessing worksheet titled 'Africa'.
#> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
my_dat
#> Source: local data frame [624 x 7]
#> 
#>    country continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap source_dat
#>      (chr)     (chr) (int)   (dbl)    (int)     (dbl)      (chr)
#> 1  Algeria    Africa  1952  43.077  9279525  2449.008     Africa
#> 2  Algeria    Africa  1957  45.685 10270856  3013.976     Africa
#> 3  Algeria    Africa  1962  48.303 11000948  2550.817     Africa
#> 4  Algeria    Africa  1967  51.407 12760499  3246.992     Africa
#> 5  Algeria    Africa  1972  54.518 14760787  4182.664     Africa
#> 6  Algeria    Africa  1977  58.014 17152804  4910.417     Africa
#> 7  Algeria    Africa  1982  61.368 20033753  5745.160     Africa
#> 8  Algeria    Africa  1987  65.799 23254956  5681.359     Africa
#> 9  Algeria    Africa  1992  67.744 26298373  5023.217     Africa
#> 10 Algeria    Africa  1997  69.152 29072015  4797.295     Africa
#> ..     ...       ...   ...     ...      ...       ...        ...

## currently only gs_read_cellfeed stores ws_title as an attribute
my_dat <- gs_gap() %>% # register public Gapminder practice sheet
  gs_read_cellfeed() %>% 
  {
    ws <- attr(., "ws_title")
    gs_reshape_cellfeed(.) %>% 
    mutate(source_dat = ws)      
  }
#> Accessing worksheet titled 'Africa'.
my_dat
#> Source: local data frame [624 x 7]
#> 
#>    country continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap source_dat
#>      (chr)     (chr) (int)   (dbl)    (int)     (dbl)      (chr)
#> 1  Algeria    Africa  1952  43.077  9279525  2449.008     Africa
#> 2  Algeria    Africa  1957  45.685 10270856  3013.976     Africa
#> 3  Algeria    Africa  1962  48.303 11000948  2550.817     Africa
#> 4  Algeria    Africa  1967  51.407 12760499  3246.992     Africa
#> 5  Algeria    Africa  1972  54.518 14760787  4182.664     Africa
#> 6  Algeria    Africa  1977  58.014 17152804  4910.417     Africa
#> 7  Algeria    Africa  1982  61.368 20033753  5745.160     Africa
#> 8  Algeria    Africa  1987  65.799 23254956  5681.359     Africa
#> 9  Algeria    Africa  1992  67.744 26298373  5023.217     Africa
#> 10 Algeria    Africa  1997  69.152 29072015  4797.295     Africa
#> ..     ...       ...   ...     ...      ...       ...        ...
```

Comment: That second approach where it accesses the attributes is great, thanks!  I'll open a GitHub issue.